# Hibernate session in threads

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, session, grails

Im having some problem with a service that acts as a listener of some events that are originated from an external library, that library creates a thread for reading comm port and send back the data to my listener (the grails service) on certain cases. 
The problem is that i cannot update the database when methods are called from the reading thread becose grails bound the hibernate session to threads.

There is any chance to get the hibernate session for that thread?? 
There is a configuration parameter to propagate or inject the session to threads??

i have seen the background thread plugin but it seems that is only useful if the thread is created by grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not getting a session because your service is not being invoked as part of a standard http request.

Grails has some convenience methods like

[withSession](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withSession.html)
[withNewSession](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html)
[withTransaction](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html)

that might fit the bill

Comment: not withSession, but withNewSession http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html

Comment: thanx @olexandr.  although the docs for that say it uses the same jdbc resources as the current session. so if there is no session will it work?