# Grails - how to save a domain object inside a Service?

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, service, grails-domain-class

I have a service and inside one of the functions i'm creating a domain object and trying to save it.
when it gets to the save part, i get the error

> No Hibernate Session bound to thread,
>   and configuration does not allow
>   creation of non-transactional one here

What do i need to do in order to save a domain object inside of a service. everything on the internet makes it look like this should just work....

**Edit:**
additional details:
I stumbled across this post
[Hibernate session in threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278090/grails-hibernate-session-in-threads)

which is a similar scenario. My service is getting called by a 3rd party API.

**Edit:**
I'm not explaining this very well. Here is more complete code

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
import com.ib.client.EWrapper;


class BrokerService implements InitializingBean, EWrapper{

    static transactional = true

    private EClientSocket m_client
    private boolean m_disconnectInProgress = false

    void afterPropertiesSet(){
       // this.setting = grailsApplication1.config.setting
       m_client = new EClientSocket(this)
       m_disconnectInProgress = false

       connect()
    }


    def boolean connect() {
        m_client.eConnect()
        if (m_client.isConnected())
            return true

        return false
 }

    def void historicalData(int reqId, String date, double open,
   double high, double low, double close, int volume, int count,
   double WAP, boolean hasGaps)
    {   
        HistoricalContractData.withNewSession{session->
            println ' just before object create'
            def hcd = new sbi.investments.HistoricalContractData()
            hcd.hc_id = reqId
            hcd.data_date = new Date().parse('yyyyMMdd', date.replace('finished-', ''))
            hcd.open = open
            hcd.high = high
            hcd.low = low
            hcd.close = close
            hcd.volume =volume
            hcd.trade_count =count
            hcd.wap = WAP
            hcd.has_gaps = hasGaps.toString()
            println ' just before save'
            hcd.save()

            if(hcd.hasErrors()){
                println '=========== ERROR! ============'
                println hcd.errors
            }
        }
 }
}
```

the 3rd party API is calling historicalData several times. With the above code, it is saving the first record, but then on the 2nd record i'm getting the error:

> Could not open Hibernate Session;
>   nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.SessionException:
>   Session is closed!

**Edit:**
so reading up on this more i think i understand what is happening.
a hibernate session is usually injected into the Service when called from the controller.
Because historicalData is being called from a 3rd party app and not via a controller, no hibernate session is getting injected into the service so it complains that the Session is closed.

So I think the real question may be, if a service is not called from a controller, how do i create a new hibernate session in order to save a grails domain model object (i.e. HistoricalContractData).
As can be seen above, withNewSession is not working. Should i be using a SessionFactory like so ?
(can't post link to source because stack overflow doesn't like it)

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class YourService  {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory // set by Dependency Injection

    public void yourMethod() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // do something with session
    }
}
```

I kind of tried this but don't understand how to use the session object in order to save the HistoricalContractData object.

Answer (score 4):

Service methods should be transactional, and have a session, by default.  If they are not, you are probably not following Grails conventions somehow:

1. Is your service in the services directory of grails-app?
2. Does your service name/file end with 'Service'?
3. Did you make the service or service method itself not transactional somehow?
4. Are you not invoking the service from a controller?
5. Are you using dependency injection to get your services into where-ever you use them?

That said, you can always create a transaction by doing

```
AnyDomainObject.withTransaction{txStatus->
// do stuff like save here
}
```

or create a new session with

```
AnyDomainObject.withNewSession{session->
// do stuff here
}
```

the code you have does not have the 'arrow' that is necessary for closures.

EDIT,  for you updates, you should checkout

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html

on how to use the session.  Basically, you should be able to do just

```
session.save(hcd)
```

Also, you *might* be able to do hcd.save() like normal in grails **after** you call the sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() -- the reason I think this might work is that method should create a new session and bind it to the current thread via threadlocal.

Comment: @hvtgotcodes thanks. I think i'm following most of those conventions. #4 no because the function historicalData in the service is getting called by a 3rd party API (another app).

Comment: @w- how is the other app getting your service?  If it is invoking it over a web request (REST api for example), then you should have a controller in front of the service.  No matter, adding the arrow as I showed should help.

Comment: @hvgotcodes as you can see above, the service implements EWrapper, which is an interface provided by the 3rd party API. "HistoricalData" is registered as a callback function that the other app uses to give me data. so the service is not being invoked via an HTTP request from a controller. it is just being...called directly. Does this help clarify?

Comment: @w- is HistoricalContractData a domain model class?

Comment: @hvtgotcodes yes it is. So reading up on this more i think i understand what might be happening. please see updated comments above and let me know if i'm totally off track with this. thanks.

Comment: @w-, can you make brokerService BrokerService?

Comment: @hvtgotcodes i changed that, but no luck. I still get the error message "Could not open Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!" when attempting to save the 2nd record.

Comment: @w--, are you saving more than one object?  It shouldn't be a problem in any case.  At this point you should post the service definition and (new) code you have.  You might also want to try irc #grails on freenode to get some realtime help.

Comment: @hvtgotcodes yes, historicalData is getting called more than once and so i'm saving more than one object. the most up to date version of the code is in the question.

Comment: @w-- i don't see where you are creating the session in your code (unless you are still using withNewSession).  I also don't see the two saves.  Can you change your method sig to 'public void historicalData(...)' instead of with def....

Comment: @w-- is this the library you are using? http://institutions.interactivebrokers.com/php/apiguide/interoperability/socket_client_java/java_ewrapper.htm#historicalData  I dont think HistoricalContractData is a grails domain object -- it appears to be a java class.  Try taking an actual domain class in your app (one in grails-app/domain) and using withNewSession.

Comment: @w-- assuming my above 2 comments dont help, try taking the Initializing bean off for the class declaration for now.  check out http://grails.org/doc/latest/ chapter 8 -- that interface isn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a transaction context for your service.  Make sure your Grails services are done [this way](http://www.grails.org/Services).

Another Grails service link:

http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/8.%20The%20Service%20Layer.html

Comment: do you mean service scope? my service is a singleton. can you help point me at some examples or docs please? thanks

Comment: can you help be more specific about what you mean by "this way" I originally followed that tutorial to create my service but documentation seems sparse on this topic.

Comment: Can't be more specific without seeing all your code.  Frankly, I don't know that I want to spend the time.  I'm going out tonight!

Comment: lol fair enough. Thankfully i can also say i'm going out tonite. I'll post more complete code tomorrow or something. Happy New Year!